# Post a json object to MVC3 controller with boolean values are always false

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have an object which contains several boolean values. but I have failed to post it to mvc3 controller, other values are successfully received by server.

```
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: 'POST',
     data: JSON.stringify(g),
     datatype: 'json',
     contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
     success: function (data) {
      }
});
```

call `JSON.stringify(g)` will return following string ( *partial )

```
"Entry":["true","false"],"Exit":"false","Speeding":["true","false"],"SpeedLimit":"110","EES_Monday":["true","false"],"EES_Tuesday":["true","false"],"EES_Wednesday":["true","false"],"EES_Thursday":["true","false"],"EES_Friday":["true","false"],"EES_Saturday":"false","EES_Sunday":"false"
```

However, my server controller failed to received boolean values

```
[HttpPost]
public String Edit(EditModel g){ }
```

with all boolean values are false. But other values are received.

What are potential causes?

I have been stuck here for the whole afternoon. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, that your booleans are coming in as a `string`. Maybe your JSON deserializer does not convert `"true"` to `true`

In static typed languages (includes C#)

```
true != "true"
```